# Unrotate/UnTranslate a Unit Vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a Unit Vector (UV1) which I am transforming using a Rotation + Translation Matrix (MT1). The result of that Rotation and Translation is again normalized to create a Unit Vector (UV2).

Given UV1 and MT1 I can calculate UV2. Given only UV2 and MT1 is it possible to calculate UV1?

Example Data:

```
    UV1 = -0.6593109902290344, -0.7511779860795417, -0.03225912882726347
    UV2 = 0.29567466528198705, -0.9546948074188073, -0.03367962288909071
    MT1 = 
    0.523051105292120300, -0.852299146133909100,  0.0019252927314616130, 2.0789077522304078E-4, 
    0.852293593813883100,  0.523035410017454600, -0.0054396517986005175, 4.457556673629903E-4, 
    0.003629214310009352,  0.004486130546903434,  0.9999833515795198000, 0.004359159108209769
```

Comment: There is no translation matrix as any linear transformation takes $0$ to $0$. Do you mean an affine transformation ?

Comment: I believe the answer is yes. UV1 is a normalized ENU vector which is then rotated into the Sensors perspective and the translation is then added. The result is normalized and gives me UV2 which is the vector from the sensor to the ENU coordinate. I need to be able to reverse this. When the sensor reports UV2 I need to calculate UV1 which is the vector in the ENU perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try to invert your problem, you might end up with two possible answers (but not more). You can assume that the rotation matrix is identity as rotation matrices take unit vectors to unit vectors and once you have inverted the problem for the identity matrix, just use the inverse of the rotation matrix to get your desired initial vector.

The translation takes the unit sphere to a sphere with a different center. And you have projected that translated sphere unto the unit sphere. When you try to find the point on the off-set sphere from the projection on the unit sphere, you have two possible candidates.

Comment: So how do I find the possible candidates?

Comment: Let $v$ be the unit vector you have with you, $b$ denote the translation vector and $R$ denote the rotation matrix. We want to find a real number $t$ such that $||tv-b||=1$. After you find $t$, the answer to your question is $R^{-1}(tv-b)$.

Comment: $||tv-b||=1 \Rightarrow t^2 -2t\langle v,b \rangle+||b||^2=1$. So you can find $t$ by solving the quadratic equation which can have $2$ roots.

Comment: Excuse my stupidity but I don't know how to solve the quadratic equation :/ Also, I don't know what the notation 2t<v,b> is. Can you explain further or possibly provide an example with the provided sample data in the question?

Comment: $\langle v, b \rangle$ is the inner product of two vectors and thus is a real number. The solution of the quadratic equation $x^2-2xp+q=0$ is given by $p \pm \sqrt{p^2-q}$. In this case, $p=\langle v, b \rangle$ and $q=||b||^2-1$

Comment: Thank you! Any suggestions on how to select the proper t value out of the 2 solutions?

Comment: Both $t$ values are proper. Unless more information is given about the initial vector, it is not possible to exactly pinpoint the vector you started off with.